# IIS 7 - Provisioning portal

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am wanting to setup our production IIS environments with a provisioning portal to ensure that deployment staff always setup sites in a uniform configuration, and that they don't actually have remote access to the servers directly.

What is the best 'simple' provisioning tool for such a purpose?

Do people write their own using something like Powershell remoting?

I don't want to install a tool like HELM or similar as it feels like it creates unnecessary bloat on top of a production environment.

features should include:

- create new website and app pool combo
- restart, start and stop application pools
- change bindings on websites

Answer (score 1):

Why not just setup remote IIS management access, provide them with user accounts that are restricted in nature and then simply train them on how to use the tool.  Its free and only depends on you to train the users on how to properly set things up.  They still won't need remote access rights to the box and will simply open the IIS management console on their local machine to make changes.  Its fairly easy to use and navigate.  Just train them on how to use the functions you need them to use.